# Adding custom domain for Google App Engine WordPress site

Tags: wordpress, google-app-engine

I recently deployed the WordPress on google app engine platform and added the custom domain to it. Post deployment of WordPress, I was given public ip address - 104.197.10.222 which can be used to access my WordPress website.
Then I wanted to access the website using custom domain - softpost.org 
I purchased the domain from godaddy.com and updated the A and AAAA records with below addresses.
    @   216.239.32.21   1 Hour
    @   216.239.34.21   1 Hour
    @   216.239.36.21   1 Hour
    @   216.239.38.21   1 Hour

```
@   2001:4860:4802:32::15   1 Hour  
@   2001:4860:4802:34::15   1 Hour  
@   2001:4860:4802:36::15   1 Hour  
@   2001:4860:4802:38::15   1 Hour

email   email.secureserver.net  1 Hour  
ftp     @                           1 Hour  
www ghs.googlehosted.com     1 Hour
```

But when I access the site using domain names softpost.org and www.softpost.org
I get below error - Please note that I waited for 2 days after updating the domain records.

Error: Not Found
The requested URL / was not found on this server.

Comment: Did you follow these instructions: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/domain ?

Comment: It sounds like your app didn't define a handler for the / route. Since you didn't post your app.yaml, it's impossible to know.